# i can not run this jsp .i do not know why

Tags: jsp, servlets

i can not run this program ,but when i put the HTML in <%%> as print ,i can run .i do not know why
     <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

```
    <%
        Connection con;
        Statement sql;
        ResultSet rs;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            String uri="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Yk";
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(uri,"root","");
            sql=con.createStatement();
            rs=sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Article");


    %>
    <html>
    <body>

    <% while(rs.next()){
        String paperid = rs.getString("id");
       String papertitle =rs.getString("title");
       String name = rs.getString("name");
    %>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">编号</td>
            <td width="100">主题</td>
            <td width="50">内容</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width = "100"><%=paperid%></td>
            <td width = "100"><%=papertitle%>
            </td>
            <td width="50"><%=name%></td>

        </tr>   
    </table>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

i can not run this program ,but when i put the HTML in <%%> as print ,i can run .i do not know why

Answer (score 1):

I think you should combine the two <%%> into one <%%> and don't put HTML in it.
Hope this will help you